# How to sort jtable according to a value generated by multiple columns?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

For example, there is a table with column A and B,

```
╔═════╗
║ A B ║
╠═════╣
║ 0 9 ║   --- 2*A + B = 9
║ 1 2 ║   --- 2*A + B = 4
║ 3 4 ║   --- 2*A + B = 10
╚═════╝
```

can I sort rows with the value generated by 2*A + B So the result would be

```
╔═════╗
║ A B ║
╠═════╣
║ 1 2 ║
║ 0 9 ║
║ 3 4 ║
╚═════╝
```

This is not a duplicate question , I want to use a row as the basic unit for comparing instead of column. Now I have already found a solution though.

Comment: If you still have trouble, please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your implementation of `Comparator`.

Comment: I worked out a solution myself in https://github.com/Nick-The-Uncharted/table-filter-sort-parser.git